# UIImagePickerController question

Tags: objective-c

In my app, I have two view controllers.   The MainViewController switches to the AlbumViewController when a button is pressed.  The AlbumVC is supposed to allow the user to select a picture from the PhotoLibrary and/or CameraRoll. So, I try to fire up the UIImagePickerController.

However, when the app runs, I don't see the UIImagePickerController at all.  Not compiler errors and no run time errors.

Can some kind soul help me!

Here is the source.....  Sam

MainViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface iNotateViewController : UIViewController {

    }

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
#import "iNotateViewController.h"

@implementation iNotateViewController

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

AlbumViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIViewController.h>

@interface AlbumViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,
                                                    UIImagePickerControllerDelegate >{

}
@end
```

**AlbumViewController.m**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
            UIImagePickerController *picker;
            picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;

            picker.delegate = self;

            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

            [picker release];       
        }
    }


    -(void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
           didFinishPickingImage: (UIImage *) image
                     editingInfo: (NSDictionary *) editingInfo {
        [self useImage:image];
        [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController *)picker {
        [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should move [picker release] to the dealloc method

Comment: Thanks for the idea....I made the 'picker' an instance variable, and moved the [picker release] to the dealloc: method.  I still don't see the picker controller.  In fact, the delegate method didFinishPickingImage: is not being called.  I set a breakpoint there, and it's not hit.

Hope this sheds more light on the problem.....

Answer (score 0):

In **AlbumViewController.m** change the following line of code in method `- (void)viewDidLoad`

From:

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

To:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```